# How to make table td taking up the whole width using css?

Tags: html, css

I am making a site with tables mobile responsive. How do I make table td take up the whole full width(100%) using css?

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>Column One</td>
        <td>Column Two</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

It is too hard to read information in two columns close to each other.

Answer (score 33):

This will show the cells one below the other:

```
td {display:block;width:99.9%;clear:both}
```

or, as noted by @nux,

```
td {display:block; box-sizing:border-box; clear:both}
```

either should be enough, although microsoft browser won't oblige and you might need proprietary markup for those; then again if people plan to use a browser on their phone they wouldn't buy a microsoft phone, so the problem is minor.

Comment: There doesn't appear to be a reason to use the clear property.  A block element automatically takes up the width of its parent.

Comment: @cimmanon I agree, but I quickly tested and I had to insert it for a browser, maybe it isn't necessary after all but I didn't spend too much time testing

Comment: in some clients (e.g android outlook app) td {display:block;} not working

Answer (score 3):

When in mobile screen, change the tr to display:flex and td set to width 100%. Like below:

```
@media screen and (max-width: 576px){
    tr {
      display: flex;
      flex-wrap: wrap;
    }
    
    td {
      width: 100%;
    }
}
```

If your table td has a border, you might want to remove the first columns of td border in mobile so that first column td content will looks like it is in the same columns with 2nd td in mobile:

```
tr td:first-child {
  border: none;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

First, you need to make sure that your table has 100% width, then you can do the same with the th and td

```
table, td {
   width: 100%;
}
```

EDIT:
since you edited your original post, you should give the first td a class

```
<td class="first">

td.first {
   width: 100%;
}
```

This will cause the first column to use as much of the page as it can and the second td will be just wide enough for the content. You may have to give it a width too if you don't want your text to wrap or something.

Comment: I think most mobile device browsers are ok with tables, but I tend to avoid them anyway and use divs or [description lists](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_dl.asp). Just my two cents worth.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I got it worked with also display:block;

Comment: Tables shouldn't be avoided because of imaginary mobile concerns.  If the table is too wide to be viewed in a mobile device, you reformat the table with media queries.

Answer (score 1):

The answers above are correct but you need to also make sure you'r td element has a reference for its 100% width otherwise it may not work. You should have this rule set at the start of your stylesheet:

```
body, html {
    width: 100%;
}
```

Take a look at this thread for more info:
[HTML table td not full width when using display block and 100% width attributes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31427570/html-table-td-not-full-width-when-using-display-block-and-100-width-attributes?rq=1)