# HTML table td not full width when using display block and 100% width attributes

Tags: html, css

I am using DISPLAY:BLOCK where appropriate on the td cells with class of column, however the logo and CALL US td cells are not stacking vertically when resized to mobile size.

It's adding 100% width to them however that's not actually taking up 100% of the screen when on mobile size.

JSFIDDLE: http://jsfiddle.net/7bm95wrm/

HTML

```
<body>
<table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="0" width="100%">
    <tr>
        <td bgcolor="#FFFFFF" align="center">
            <table width="650px" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="3" class="container">
                <tr>
                    <td class="alignright greytext" style="font-size: 12px;">Having problems reading this email. Don't panic! <a href="#" class="bold">Click here</a> an you can read it in a browser.</td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td class="navbar navbar-inverse" align="center">
            <!-- This setup makes the nav background stretch the whole width of the screen. -->
            <table width="650px" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="3" class="container">
                <tr class="navbarbg navbar-inverse">
                    <td class="column"><img src="images/logo.jpg" alt="" title="" width="216" height="54" /></td>
                    <td colspan="2">
                        <table class="whitetext" width="400">
                          <tr>
                            <td class="smalltext alignright" valign="bottom">
                                Call: 0161 482 7650<br />
                                <h2 class="lucidafont">More from Leasing</h2>
                            </td>
                          </tr>
                        </table>
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td bgcolor="#FFFFFF" align="center">
            <table width="650px" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="3" class="container toppadding">
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        <h1 class="bluetext">Thank you for downloading<br /> the Leasing Landscape</h1>
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td class="greytext bodytext">
                        <h2 class="bluetext">Dear [name],</h2>
                        <p>Thank you for downloading the Leasing Landscape - we're sure you'll find it useful.</p>
                        <p>To view your copy of the guide, please click here: <a href="#" alt="" title="">[link]</a></p>
                        <p>Regards,</p>
                        <h2 class="bluetext">The team at CH&amp;L</h2>
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td bgcolor="#FFFFFF" align="center">
            <table width="650px" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="3" class="container">
                <tr>
                    <td colspan="5">
                        <hr>
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td colspan="5" style="text-align:center;">
                        <a href="#" alt="" title=""><img src="images/twitter.jpg" alt="" title="" /></a>
                        <a href="#" alt="" title=""><img src="images/facebook.jpg" alt="" title="" /></a>
                        <a href="#" alt="" title=""><img src="images/googleplus.jpg" alt="" title="" /></a>
                        <a href="#" alt="" title=""><img src="images/linkedin.jpg" alt="" title="" /></a>
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr style="text-align:center;">
                    <td colspan="6" style="font-size: 12px;" class="greytext">
                        <p>Copyright &copy; 2000-2015 Really Good Domains Ltd. All rights reserved.</p>
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr style="text-align:center; font-size: 12px;" class="copyright">
                    <td class="bold column"><a href="#" alt="" title="">Terms &amp; Conditions</a></td>
                    <td class="bold"><a href="#" alt="" title="">Privacy</a></td>
                    <td class="bold"><a href="#" alt="" title="">Cookies</a></td>
                    <td class="bold"><a href="#" alt="" title="">Accessibility</a></td>
                    <td class="bold"><a href="#" alt="" title="">Sitemap</a></td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

CSS

```
body { font-family: Lucida Grande,Lucida Sans Unicode,Lucida Sans,Geneva,Verdana,sans-serif; }
    td {  }
    .alignright { text-align: right; }
    .navbarbg { background-color: #283791; color: #ffffff; height: 75px; }
    hr {  }
    h1,h2,h3,h4,h5,h6 { font-family: Arial Bold,Gadget,sans-serif; margin: 0; }
    a { color: #283790; }
    .whitetext { color: #ffffff; }
    .bluetext { color: #283790; }
    .greytext { color: #9f9f9f; }
    .smalltext { font-size: 14px; }
    .bodytext { font-size: 13px; padding-top: 20px; }
    .lucidafont { font-family: Lucida Grande,Lucida Sans Unicode,Lucida Sans,Geneva,Verdana,sans-serif; }
    .toppadding { padding-top: 20px; padding-bottom: 10px; }
    .bold { font-weight: bold; }
    /* .copyright td { border-right: 1px solid #000; height: 5px; }
    .copyright td:last-child { border-right: none; } */
    @media screen and (max-width:480px) {
        table {
            width: 100%!important;
        }
    }
    @media only screen and (max-width: 480px) {
        table[class="body_table"] {
            width: 440px!important;
        }

        table td[class="column"] {
            width:100%!important;
            display: block!important;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

1st thing is that you need to make the `html` and `body` `100%` so that it takes the whole *browser / view-port* width

then, the child element on setting `100%` will take parents width, which is `html / body` in this case

Problem in your markup is that you set `width=100%` for `table`, so table tries to take `100%` of its parent(html/body in your case), and, they are only as wide as content on the page, so whole width is not occupied.

Update your markup as below :

```
html,body {
    font-family: Lucida Grande, Lucida Sans Unicode, Lucida Sans, Geneva, Verdana, sans-serif;
    width:100%;
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
}
table{
    width:100%;
}
```

On a general note, take this below markup and understand the comment

```
<div class="div_1">div 1
    <div class="div_2">div 2</div>
</div>
<div class="div_3">div 3</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.div_1 {
    width:100%; /*of HTML/Body if width is set, else content width*/
    border:1px solid red;
}
.div_2 {
    width:50%; /*50% of div_1 width*/
    border:1px solid green;
}
.div_3 {
    width:70%; /*50% of HTML / Body width - notice markup*/
    border:1px solid blue;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for this. However it's the content within the blue header section which needs to stack vertically (via using 100% width on both I suppose). The logo and content to the right of it.

Comment: so you want only the blue header to span 100% width? I think m not getting you clearly.. *needs to stack vertically*?

Comment: The content inside of it (when viewed on a mobile). This is to be an email template.
[Logo] and then [Call Us] under it. Below 480px viewport.

Comment: @JordanC26 :like this => http://jsfiddle.net/7bm95wrm/2/ ?
You gotta need adjust your media queries for your requirement

Comment: I don't see any difference, resize the viewport and the call us details at the top right just get squashed against the logo.

Comment: mmmm......can you just mention the exact layout and view port width you wana have?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/83311/discussion-between-noobeditor-and-jordanc26).

Comment: perfect! This was driving me crazy. If you dont have the body/html elements set to 100% then td's have no reference for their 100% width.

Comment: @rhysclay : right...generally its a good practice to set them to 100% by default unless you are targeting specific width!!

Answer (score 0):

You are using `display: block` for one `td` only, I think you need to apply the same to its sibling `td` too

```
 <tr class="navbarbg navbar-inverse">
      <td class="column"><img src="images/logo.jpg" alt="" title="" width="216" height="54" /></td>
                <td colspan="2" class="column">
                    <table class="whitetext" width="400">
                      <tr>
                        <td class="smalltext alignright" valign="bottom">
                            Call: 0161 482 7650<br />
                            <h2 class="lucidafont">More from Leasing</h2>
                        </td>
                      </tr>
                    </table>
                </td>
            </tr>
```

see this updated fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/ajiths4u/7bm95wrm/1/